# Where is the Spotlight icon being used?

Tags: ios, icons, spotlight

There is a *Spotlight search results icon* entry in the [guidelines for iOS app icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html). However in the search results screen in iOS 9.3, I see that **only the main app icon gets displayed in the search result** – not the spotlight icon.

Question is, where is the spotlight icon gets used now? What action the user can do to view this spotlight icon on the device?

Answer (score -2):

Spotlight icon used for apps, documents, images and other files. In OS X Yosemite, Spotlight suggestions provides additional results like Wikipedia, news sites, Maps, iTunes, movie listings, and more.

To open Spotlight, click the magnifying glass icon in the upper-right corner of the menu bar, or press Command-Space from any app.

Comment: The question is about iOS.